# How to implement two separate featured images for each post/page

Tags: post-thumbnails, customization

So I would like to set two separate feature images for each post/page. One would be a rectangle for use in a slider and another would be a square for use on archive pages, search pages, category pages.

WordPress can do this, but it either resizes the initial image to the nearest resolution or crops it. I would rather create it myself and upload it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multiple-post-thumbnails/) is what you're searching for...

Comment: This is very helpful. No idea how I missed this while searching!